# Carbonating a keg outside of a fridge until it is ready

Tags: kegging

My refrigerator is full but I am kegging two Saisons today.

I plan on letting them sit in room temperature for 2 weeks and then moving them into the refrigerator when they are fully carbonated.

Given that my room temperature in the day is about 78F, but my refrigerator is 40*F, how do I set the PSI to account for the change in temperature 2 weeks from now?

Do I simply set the PSI to account for room temperature, and then change the PSI downward after I move the kegs into the colder environment?

Answer (score 1):

The pressure will drop when you chill the kegs, and 'volumes of CO2' is constant (when the keg is closed).

You find your target 'volumes' on your favorite carbonation table, follow the curve through the higher temps, and extrapolate a line out to 78F (off the bottom of any chart I have).

My guess from the chart at [kegerators.com](http://www.kegerators.com/carbonation-table.php) would around 30psi at 78F.

I also think it's better to end up higher than low - I have taken all the CO2 out of a keg of clear beer in less than an hour by pulling the relief valve and shaking it. Putting it back seems to take longer.